# Short, case-insensitive string obfuscation strategy

Tags: java, encryption, obfuscation

I am looking for a way to identify (i.e. encode **and** decode) a set of Java strings with one token. The identification should not involve DB persistence. So far I have looked into Base64 encoding and DES encryption, but both are not optimal with respect to the following requirements:

- Token should be as short as possible
- Token should be insensitive to casing
- Token should survive a URLEncoder/Decoder round-trip (i.e. will be used in URLs)

Is Base32 my best shot or are there better options? Note that I'm primarily interested in shortening & obfuscating the set, encryption/security is not important.

Comment: *"I'm primarily interested in shortening and obfuscating..."*  This looks very, very, close to what obfuscators like *Proguard* are doing with class and method names. Can't you simply write your own shortening method and keep a dictionary of the mappings on the server side? First *String* (lowercased) you encounter could become "a", second one could become "b", etc.  As long as you keep track of the mapping somewhere (no need for a DB: you could maybe keep the mapping in the session?) you can recreate your strings. That would be quite similar to what *Proguard* does.  Would it work?

Comment: The phrase "should not involve DB persistence" was meant to imply "no need to keep track of the mapping" -- the mechanism should work across sessions, or even across applications, if they use the same encode/decode utility.

Comment: Your suggestions are strange.  Base64 is a binary encoding scheme, with no encryption features.  DES is an encryption scheme, with no encoding features.  They are completely orthogonal (and unrelated) to each other.  Nobody says you cannot Base64 a DES-encrypted string and vice versa.  The only seeming similarity between are two is that they both yield output that is not plain text, and a lot of things can yield output that is not text, Rot13 being one of them as suggested in one of the answers.

Comment: Token length merely affects security level, so you can use any length of token you want with any encryption method.  Your tokens can be converted to lower/upper-case before encryption, so case-sensitivity is not an issue -- although again it affects security level.  And obviously any output from an encryption method, after proper URL encoding, will round-trip -- that's the definition of URL encoding in the first place!

Comment: Figure out whether you want encoding or encryption, or merely obfuscation.  They are completely different things.  Not sure why Base64 or DES do not serve your needs, as all your three requirements are satisfied with Base64 and DES (Base64 does not use a token).

Comment: @netzwerg: you didn't mention it was meant to work across sessions etc.  Depending on how big your encode/decode utility can be you could include a fixed mapping directly into your encode/decode utility class: it could help both reduce the size and obfuscate your strings if you have at least some knowledge as to what the strings would contain.  But I take it that now you're going to say *"Won't work, my strings are made up of random characters"*, etc.   ; )

Comment: @user988052 No objections against a fixed mapping (see my comment below kan's answer)

Comment: @StephenChung I think I'm aware of the difference between encoding/encryption/obfuscation. As you point out correctly, all I want is output that is not plain text and is as short as possible. Moreover, case-insensitivity is a requirement for the token, not the input string (that's why Base64 won't work).

Comment: @netzwerg: btw do you need to be able to encode/decode both on the client and on the server sides or just on the server side? *(you commented below kan's answer that the user was to choose a subset so I'm wondering)*

Comment: @user988052 Server side is enough. User selects a subset of strings through standard form checkboxes and gets a server-generated token in return. The token is then used to request the set of strings (via potentially different app which uses same mapping heuristics).

Comment: @netzwerg Is the range of characters from which your Strings are comprised known? If so, what is it?

Comment: @netzwerg, I think I get it.  You want something that will encode some text into a bunch of characters which you can just lump into a URL and have it suffer no ill effects.  Therefore, you need the encoding scheme to output text that is non-case-sensitive (since URL's are not case sensitive) and it must survive a round-trip (therefore, it cannot be something that conflicts with standard URL encoding characters).  And with these satisfied, you want the encoded string to be as short as possible (so your URL's can be short). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @netzwerg, if my understanding is correct, why don't you try these following steps: 1) zip the text, which should yield up to 90% savings for a program fragment or 60% for small texts, 2) encode the zipped stream by encoding each byte in hex.  Step #2 will double the size of the zipped stream, but #1 will likely save 60-80%.  Therefore, your encoded output should be around 30-40% of the length of your original text.  It round-trips because hex (0-9,A-F) is non-case-sensitive and does not conflict with any standard URL encoding special characters.

Comment: @StephenChung Yes, your understanding is correct and your suggestion would be quite optimal if I really needed to encode the full strings. However (as commented below kan's answer) _"I have a well-defined set of strings from which users select a sub-set. It's these picks that I want to encode in a token"_. Thus, encoding the full strings is unnecessary. Instead I will represent just the picks with a binary number which I'll then encode in base32 (which is even shorter than hex).

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, the range of characters is known (a-zA-Z0-9), but when speaking of case-insensitivity/URL-compatibility I meant the token, not the input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's a structure of the text (i.e. set of strings)? You could use your knowledge of it to encode it in a shorten form. E.g. if you have large base-decimal number "1234567890" you could translate it into 36-base number, which will be shorter.

Otherwise it looks like you are trying invent an universal archiver.

If you don't care about length, then yes, processing by alphabet based encoder (such as Base32) is the only choice.

Also, if text is large enough, maybe you could save some space by gzipping it.

Comment: I have a well-defined set of strings from which users select a sub-set. It's these picks that I want to encode in a token. In my first shot at it, I represented the universe vs. picks as a binary number, converted it to a decimal number, based-64 encoded it, and wired it through a URL encoder. Thanks for stating the obvious (which I missed): 36-base is shorter than decimal ;-)

Comment: Yes, just binary number is ideal for you then. You could use also some more symbols which will survive url-encoders. So, you could use `a-z0-9/|_.()$*',~-` - 48-base encoding! But double check if these characters are actually url-friendly.

Comment: @kan: Most of the characters you wrote there are not URL-friendly.  RFC3986 defines only four (!) unreserved characters in addition to a-zA-Z0-9 so the OP may find it problematic to do Base48.  Now if you were to get creative and use a fragmented URL (an URL with a "fragment part") etc. you may get around the limitation but still...

Comment: @user988052 It depends in which part of url she places the string. If it's a host name it's very restricted. But for a query string parameter (most likely place for it) value it's less restricted, e.g. it could have the `:` unquoted.

Answer (score 2):

Rot13 obfuscates but does not shorten.  Zip shortens (usually) but does not survive the URL round trip.  Encryption will not shorten, and may lengthen.  Hashing shortens but is one-way.  You do not have an easy problem.    Base32 is case insensitive, but takes more space than Base64, which isn't.  I suspect that you are going to have to drop or modify your requirements.  Which requirements are most important and which least important?

Comment: Thanks for the systematic review -- exactly my chain of thought!

Answer (score 1):

I have spent some time on this and I have a good solution for you.

Encode as base64 then as a custom base32 that uses 0-9a-v. Essentially, you lay out the bits 6 at a time (your chars are 0-9a-zA-Z) then encode them 5 at a time. This leads to hardly any extra space. For example, `ABCXYZdefxyz123789` encodes as `i9crnsuj9ov1h8o4433i14`

Here's an implementation that works, including some test code that proves it is case-insensitive:

```
// Note: You can add 1 more char to this if you want to
static String chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

private static String decodeToken(String encoded) {
    // Lay out the bits 5 at a time
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : encoded.toLowerCase().getBytes())
        sb.append(asBits(chars.indexOf(b), 5));

    sb.setLength(sb.length() - (sb.length() % 6));

    // Consume it 6 bits at a time
    int length = sb.length();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 6)
        result.append(chars.charAt(Integer.parseInt(sb.substring(i, i + 6), 2)));

    return result.toString();
}

private static String generateToken(String x) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : x.getBytes())
        sb.append(asBits(chars.indexOf(b), 6));

    // Round up to 5 bit multiple
    // Consume it 5 bits at a time
    int length = sb.length();
    sb.append("00000".substring(0, length % 5));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 5)
        result.append(chars.charAt(Integer.parseInt(sb.substring(i, i + 5), 2)));

    return result.toString();
}

private static String asBits(int index, int width) {
    String bits = "000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(index);
    return bits.substring(bits.length() - width);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "ABCXYZdefxyz123789";
    String token = generateToken(input);
    System.out.println(input + " ==> " + token);
    Assert.assertEquals("mixed", input, decodeToken(token));
    Assert.assertEquals("lower", input, decodeToken(token.toLowerCase()));
    Assert.assertEquals("upper", input, decodeToken(token.toUpperCase()));
    System.out.println("pass");
}
```

Comment: +1 For extra effort (even after I had already accepted an answer). As commented below my question, I plan to represent the picks vs. universe as a binary number and then encode it with Base32 or something hand-crafted along the lines of your suggestion. Thus "input" would be something like "1000111000" (4 picks among set of 10 well-defined items).

Comment: I have long string that have > 1000 chars, is it possible to use above solution? I had tried it but i am getting IndexoutofBoundException in generateToken() code. Please verify it.

Comment: @vbjain large string length should have no impact. what line gives you the error? can you debug it and figure out why it's failing?

Comment: Input string i have tried is, String input = "ABCXYZdefxyz123789ABCXYZdefxyz123789ABCXYZdefxyz123789ABCXYZdefxyz123789ABCXYZdefxyz123789ABCXYZdefxyz123789ABCXYZdefxyz123789ABCXYZdefxyz123789ABCXYZdefxyz123789ABCXYZdefxyz123789ABCXYZdefxyz123789ABCXYZdefxyz123789ABCXYZdefxyz123789ABCXYZdefxyz123789"; This is giving me, String index out of range: 1515 error for line, result.append(chars.charAt(Integer.parseInt(sb.substring(i, i + 5), 2))); in  generateToken() method. I am also checking the issue, let me know if you find it soon. Thanks.

Comment: @vbjain bytes 80 and 81 (between `d` and `e`) are both `0x3F`, so your input is not "normal"